# Gemfire CacheListenerAdapter implementation ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxType

Tags: spring-xd, gemfire, geode

I'm getting the following error when I tried to implement CacheListenerAdapter from gemfire.

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxType`

I am using the following code for getting the cache values from gemfire.

`import com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.Declarable;
import com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.EntryEvent;
import com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.util.CacheListenerAdapter;
import com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl;`

`@Override
  public void afterUpdate(EntryEvent<K, V> event) {
      addToQueue((PdxInstanceImpl) event.getNewValue());
  }`

and I'm reading the price using the following code in `addToQueue` function

`Double price = Double.parseDouble(instance.readField("Price").toString());`

Please note that I copied this code from another project and I'm new to gemfire. I use the above code to plot data in a window.

Comment: What version of GemFire are you running on the client and server? It looks like you might have 8.2 on the client and 9.x on the server as the product's package names changed between those versions. There is a backwards compatibility layer, so I think this shouldn't be a problem, but please can you provide that detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client needs to be running v8.2.2 or later.  Code to translate the org.apache.geode package names to com.gemstone.gemfire was added in that release.

Comment: I was using client v8.1.0 now I updated to v8.2.2 and everything is working fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

following error you can get because of gemfire server and client has diffrent jar version.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxType
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.ClassPathLoader.forName(ClassPathLoader.java:422) ~[gemfire-8.2.0.jar:na]
```

For debugging issue you need to check error logs

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.ClassPathLoader.forName(ClassPathLoader.java:422) ~[gemfire-8.2.0.jar:na]
```

You can see "gemfire-8.2.0.jar" now check your server version and change client jar as per server .